# How do i iterate pandas columns by different id and concat the output?

Tags: pandas, dictionary, append, concatenation

I'm working with some OBD2 telematics data, I managed to convert the JSON type data into a pandas data frame, however, I also need to deal with the nested dictionary which contains multiples keys. Below is the example data

```
d =  [{'id':'001','0':{'speed':10 , 'voltage':12.3 ,'overspeedCount':2},'1':{'speed':50 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :1},'2':{'speed':50 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :1}}, {'id':'002','0':{'speed':13 , 'voltage':12.1 ,'overspeedCount' :1},'1':{'speed':40 ,'voltage':12.1 ,'overspeedCount' :0}, '2':{'speed':25 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :3}}]
```

I need to transform the above to pandas data frame which doesn't consist dict

I managed to transform d into pandas dataframe using the following code ;

```
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and concat the first two column data by maintaining id using the following approach ;

```
pd.concat([pd.merge(test[['id']],test['0'].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True),
         pd.merge(test[['id']],test['1'].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)]).reset_index()
```

however in the real data , i have more than 2 column .. understood that we need to use 'for' loop and i'm stuck here

```py
d =  [{'id':'001','0':{'speed':10 , 'voltage':12.3 ,'overspeedCount':2},'1':{'speed':50 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :1},'2':{'speed':50 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :1}}, {'id':'002','0':{'speed':13 , 'voltage':12.1 ,'overspeedCount' :1},'1':{'speed':40 ,'voltage':12.1 ,'overspeedCount' :0}, '2':{'speed':25 , 'voltage':12.2 ,'overspeedCount' :3}}]

 pd.DataFrame(d)


 pd.concat([pd.merge(test[['id']],test['0'].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True),
         pd.merge(test[['id']],test['1'].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)]).reset_index()
```

also tried the following (by considering converting column str to int) but end up error messages

```
n=0


for col in test.columns[n]:

pd.concat([pd.merge(test[['id']],test[n].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True),
         pd.merge(test[['id']],test[n+1].apply(pd.Series),how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)]).reset_index()

n+1
```

[Dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQBgO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `apply`. You may construct the new `df` directly using `from_records` and `np.repeat` for index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
s = df.pop('id')
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.stack().values, index=np.repeat(s, df.shape[1]))

Out[1051]:
     overspeedCount  speed  voltage
id
001  2               10     12.3
001  1               50     12.2
001  1               50     12.2
002  1               13     12.1
002  0               40     12.1
002  3               25     12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index('id')
res = df.stack()
res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)
res = res.apply(lambda x: list(x.values()))
pd.DataFrame(res.values.tolist(), index=res.index, columns=['speed','voltage','overspeedCount'])
```

Output

```
     speed  voltage  overspeedCount
id                                 
001     10     12.3               2
001     50     12.2               1
001     50     12.2               1
002     13     12.1               1
002     40     12.1               0
002     25     12.2               3
```

Comment: thanks for your solution @Stef, the stack approach really give me idea to work on with my original data